# SqlServer 08: Query to list all databases in an instance?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-express, sqlcmd

How do I list all the databases for a given sql server 08 instance using sqlcmd?

Answer (score 50, accepted):

```
sqlcmd -E -S SERVER\INSTANCE -Q "sp_databases"
```

---

Notes:

- `-E`: Use a trusted connection ("Windows authentication"). Replace by `-U username -P password` for SQL Server authentication.
- `-S SERVER\INSTANCE`: The instance of SQL Server to which to connect. If you don't know the name of your instance, you can use `sqlcmd -L` to get a list.
- `-Q`: The query to execute. The uppercase `Q` causes sqlcmd to exit after executing the query.

Answer (score 39):

To elaborate with more detail for the sqlcmd newbie:

```
C:\> sqlcmd -S <the_server_name>
1> select name from sys.databases
2> go
```

Comment: Where do I find out what the server name is? Is there a command to list all the servers?

Comment: @FelixEve: https://stackoverflow.com/q/141154/87698

Answer (score 34):

```
EXEC sp_databases
```

or

```
SELECT NAME FROM sys.sysdatabases
```

or

```
EXEC sp_msForEachDB 'PRINT ''?''';
```

Comment: Up voted for options but accepted Heinzi because it includes the sqlcmd aspect. Thanks!

Comment: I'm a newb and may be stating the obvious here, but I had to do 'go' after the EXEC line like this `1>EXEC  sp_databases<ENTER>2>go<ENTER>`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [sp_databases](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176070.aspx) stored procedure.