# Select available

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-connection

Trying to write a small C# application that is going to be distributed to some computers in an organisation. These computers may or may not have a version of a database installed. I am expecting a flavor of MS SQL server, but if none is installed I would like to invite the user to download and install the CE (Compact Edition).

Is there a way to check which database systems are installed, and to produce a valid connection string based on the information gathered?

I am assuming that the full versions of the SQLServer is able to communicate with the .sdf/.mdf files that the CE is using. Is that a wrong assumption?

Comment: shouldn't your database be installed in server as central point of storage.

Comment: this question may help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2443001/check-if-sql-server-is-installed-on-a-machine-through-c-sharp