# How to check whether SQL Server 2005 or 2008 is installed

Tags: c#, sql-server

I am looking for ways of programmatically checking whether SQL Server 2005 or 2008 is installed on a particular machine.

With some MS packages it is as easy as checking `Install` values in registry on a certain path. For instance to check for Full NET 4 one would need to look at `HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\NET Framework Setup\NDP\v4\Full`.

Is there a similar thing for SQL Server? I am looking for the real thing, not the "Express". How can I make a distinction? Also, any individual check for 2005, 2008 or R2 or a cumulative check is fine.

Additionally, I am not restricting myself to registry. If the check includes file system search, that is perfectly fine too.

I have found a few answers like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2381055/check-if-sql-server-any-version-is-installed) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions) but they do not fill my cup entirely.

Comment: Why don't the linked answers suffice?

Comment: Well, for one I don't know how to make a distinction between Express and full version and this is rather important for me.

Comment: Ah, I understand now. See below.

Answer (score 5):

The only supported way to figure out the edition is to connect to it and execute

```
Select ServerProperty('Edition')
```

Comment: Thanks! I am still looking for a complete solution towards getting the complete list of local SQL Servers. I have tried all code from other posts and none of them provides a complete solution. Usually there is at least a problem with default instance not being enumerated.