# Sql Browser not returning all sql instances on a machine

Tags: sql-server, ssms, sqlbrowser

I have 2 instances of Sql Server on my pc:

A named instance of Sql Express (\SQLEXPRESS) 
And a default instance of Sql Developer edition.

Using SSMS, when I browse for servers on my machine, I only get the Sql Express instance listed as being available on my machine.

I know that I have the server itself configured and accessible because if I type the connection string manually, I can connect to it via Sql Authentication and Windows Authentication both locally and from other machines. And I know the Sql Browser is at least returning some information as the Sql Express instance is browsable.

After some googling for a solution, the closest information I can find to my problem is this [MSDN Article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143799.aspx). However, as far as I know, I haven't changed the name of my computer since the OS was installed (Win 7 x64) let alone since Sql was installed.

Any ideas about why the browser doesn't recognise the other instance greatly appreciated.

Thanks Andy

Comment: @Andy can you specify your versions of MSSQL instances ? Did you read this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087.aspx. See section `Hiding SQL Server`. Check network ports assigned to your Sql dev edition.

Comment: @Johnny, both instances are version 10.1.2531.0. The Express version is on dynamic ports as it is not the default instance, the Developer Edition is installed as the default instance and so is statically set on port 1433.

Comment: @Johnny, also, I was not aware of the hide instance option, but I have checked the settings and the instance is not hidden.

Comment: I have just switched off the SQL Browser service and as expected could not find the \SQLEXPRESS instance. The default instance is now visible (presumably because it is the default instance, browsing for servers will check ports 1433 and 1434). But this begs the question why is the browser masking the instance?

Comment: @Andy did you try to reinstall SQL Browser service ? If not try to do this.

Comment: @Johnny, I finally got around to re-installing the browser but it hasn't changed anything.

Answer (score 0):

if the HideInstance Flag is No for both the instances and still not showing 
check out these 2 Posts in [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions) and [DBA.Stackexchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/18499/why-does-sqlcmd-lc-not-show-the-local-instance)

and try this registry Key

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\90\SQL Browser\SsrpListener
```

make sure it has value `1`
if you cant find it under 90 folder, search for `SsrpListener` because if you read the background section of [SQL Browser service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181087.aspx) , you see that browser service was originally SQL Server Resolution Protocol (SSRP)