# How do I to find out if I have a local SQL Server 2008 R2 installed

Tags: sql-server

They have installed SQL Server 2008 R2 on my work machine.

Connecting to (local) win auth does not seem to work. How do I determine if I have a local instance of it?

thanks

Comment: Check your SQL Server Configuration Manager to see if there are any instances.

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions

Comment: What exactly do you want to know? If there is **any** SQL Server installed, or if SQL Server **2008 R2** is installed? Just connecting to local with win auth would work with any version of SQL Server.

Comment: Just want to make sure that Sql server was installed locally ,that I am running locally and not pointing to the server.At the minute I can only seem to connect to a database that is on the network.Trying to logon with (local) win I have not success.Could it be that it was installed with a named instance?In a nutshell I want to install some db locally.(NOT sql express)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your SQL Server Configuration Manager.

[image]

If there isn't an instance running, follow this tutorial: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190699.aspx

You also want to make sure your instance is a Network Service. For your instance, right click on it, then click properties. Set Log On As - Built in Account: Network Service.

[image]