# Create and Attach Database in SQL Server 2005 Express

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2005, sql-server-2005-express

I want to dynamically (through code at run time) find a SQL Server instance installed on the target PC, then create a database and finally attach my MDF file.

Is it Possible? How can I do that? (I'm using C# Framework 3.5 Visual Studio 2008)

Comment: To find all available instances on a machine, this has been asked again and again every few days lately: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions

Comment: Also, you either want to create a database or attach an existing database. You don't create a database and then attach an MDF file...