# Get list of all sql servers installed in the system

Tags: c#, sql-server, drop-down-menu

I am trying to get list of all SQL Servers installed in the machine and populate them in a drop downlist.  I have searched in google and tried the following:

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

namespace SMOTest
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
           DataTable dt = SmoApplication.EnumAvailableSqlServers(false);
           if (dt.Rows.Count > 0)
           {
              foreach (DataRow dr in dt.Rows)
              {
                 Console.WriteLine(dr["Name"]);
              }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

However I didn't find a reference for Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

What is the best way to get all the sqlserver names and populate it in a drop down list?

Comment: Maybe it helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions

Comment: @Samich I dont want instances and their references

Comment: @ShaliniPavan If you don't want SQL Server instances then you should  update your question to make it clear what you do what - at the moment the question seems very much like you are asking for a list of SQL Server instances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dont find it than you can google it and than you can pass the reference of it the simplest way to achive it.

Check this answer : http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlsmoanddmo/thread/883d89df-fb19-4b04-ab83-1006a3559476/

Do Install : [Microsoft SQL Server 2008 Feature Pack, October 2008](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=8824)