# Bypass installation of SQLExpress if there's an instance of Microsoft SQL Server

Tags: .net, windows, installation, windows-installer, bootstrapper

I've developed a .net project and now im doing the installer. My project requires either Microsoft SQL 2008 or Microsoft SQL 2008 Express. I've created a Bootstrapper that installs the Microsoft SQL 2008 Express and it works fine except when someone has Microsoft SQL 2008 already installed. How can i bypass the installation if Microsoft SQL 2008 is already installed?

**Edit:**
This solution works for Microsoft SQL 2008:

```
<Product xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper" ProductCode="AAA">
   <InstallChecks>
      <RegistryCheck Property="IsInstalled" Key="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL" Value="SQL2008" />
   </InstallChecks>

   <Commands Reboot="Defer">
      <Command PackageFile="setup.exe" EstimatedInstallSeconds="15" >
         <InstallConditions>
            <BypassIf Property="IsInstalled" Compare="ValueExists" />
         </InstallConditions>
      </Command>
   </Commands>

   ...

</Product>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To be honest I am not an expert in what your trying to do. But would the SQL server discovery report work for you? : [SQL server discovery report](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510455.aspx)

or

[determine-installed-sql-server-instances](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions)

Edit:

I was thinking about something like:

```
<Product xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/2004/01/bootstrapper" ProductCode="AAA">
   <InstallChecks>
      <RegistryCheck Property="IsInstalled" Key="HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names" Value="SQL" />
   </InstallChecks>

   <Commands Reboot="Defer">
      <Command PackageFile="setup.exe" EstimatedInstallSeconds="15" >
         <InstallConditions>
            <BypassIf Property="IsInstalled" Compare="ValueExists" />
         </InstallConditions>
      </Command>
   </Commands>

   ...

</Product>
```

Comment: I'm not sure if this could be used with the bootstrapper, the bootstrapper contains an xml file which has the rules for the installation. I need to know how to make a rule, that does what I asked. Another thing, may be someone has not set up this feature.

Comment: How about this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10309861/how-to-force-sqlexpresschk-exe-from-bootstrapper-to-check-for-other-instance-tha ?

Comment: I've read it, but I agree with the OP. This does not solve the problem at installation time. The clue may be with the tag <BypassIf>  (with the appropiate property value) or with the tag <InstallChecks> but i haven't figure it out yet. Thanks for your effort!!

Comment: No problem. I wrote the basic concept I would test in an edit

Comment: Your welcome, I am glad I could help. Could you post the final solution you used for future visitors?

Comment: @jsaye: could you post the solution. I have the same iisue