# How to see if database is installed

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I'm using Visual Studio 2010 Premium and I just wonder if there is a way to see if the database SQL Server 2008 Express is already installed? I read somewhere that if you have the Professional version of Visual Studio it's installed!?

Simple question, but just want to check before I download and install the database. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To check if SQL Server is installed, you can check if this registry key
exists: HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Microsoft SQL Server

For the version, I'm not sure since I don't have different versions of
SQL Server installed.
On my computer, the registry path
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\MICROSOFT\Microsoft SQL
Server\80\Tools\Client Setup\Current Version
exists. In this key, you can read the string "CurrentVersion". In my
case it's 8.00.194.

Best Regards,

or for the alternate you can use

[Alternate resource for verfying Sql instance](http://learningsqlserver.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/what-version-of-sql-server-do-i-have/)

Comment: OK, I used the control panel and found the Microsoft SQL 2008 Server. But whats the difference to the Express version? Can I also download that and install it?

Comment: [Check this link for Sql version](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions) if you SQL express edition installed and can found in services then u dont need to install.  else u can install just go on google and write download SQL expression ( specify Edition 2005/2008 watever suits to your requirement ).

Comment: Remember SQL Express Edition is a limited version with full features that are found in enterprise one!