# What's the SQL Server Express name after installing VS2012?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio-2012

I just installed VS2012 in my machine.

I'm trying to create a database but in order to create a sql connection I need the Server name, it use to be .\sqlexpress in VS2010, but apparently it changed, but I don't know the new name.

Can anybody tell what's this name?

[image]

Comment: Look Here [How can I determine installed SQL Server instances and their versions?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions

Comment: VS2010 installed SqlExpress but VS2012 does not - it comes however with localdb as pointed below by Rafael

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The name of the instance is: "(LocalDb)\v11.0"

Comment: Also, if you open up a project in VS2012 that was configured to use SqlExpress, you'll get a warning message with this information.

Answer (score 0):

I think default instance is called `.\SqlExpress`

But if you are not sure about name of SQL Server instance you can always open up SQL Server Configuration Manager and it should have that local instance listed in it.