# How to find server name for SQL Server 2005

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have installed SQL Server 2005 on my system. After installation, when I try to use it, it is asking for server name. I have tried

```
.     .\     .\SQLEXPRESS     local    (local)    localhost     .\localhost 
(localhost)    computername    .computername
```

in Windows authentication. But I was unable to connect to SQL Server. Please help me to connect.

Comment: You want to find it via `asp.net` ?

Comment: Have you looked at the SQL Server Configuration Manager?

Comment: try with `.` to connect

Comment: It will be MachineName\InstanceName. Default instance name is SQLExpress. Quick way if you haven't installed the tools, would be to have a look at windows services.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I determine installed SQL Server instances and their versions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions)

Comment: Which **edition** did you install? If you used SQL Server **Express**, the default instance name is `SQLEXPRESS`, so you should be able to connect with `.\SQLEXPRESS` or `(local)\SQLEXPRESS` or `machinename\SQLEXPRESS`. If you installed any other edition, it's just `.` or `(local)` or `machinename`

Comment: CodeCaster is right it is the duplication.

Answer (score 3):

Check this path to find `SQL Server Configuration Manager`:

```
C:\Windows\system32\SQLServerManager.msc
```

Also check this path:

`C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL<server_version>.<instance_name>\`

Server Instance Name:

[image: proof]

Another way to find find local server name:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

install managment studio and find name of the server or go to the sql server configuration manager.

Comment: Thank you Sebastian Wasik. But in my system I can not find sql server configuration manager. Is this mean that it is not correctly installed?

Comment: C:\Windows\SysWOW64\mmc.exe /32 C:\WINDOWS\SysWOW64\SQLServerManager11.msc   my path to the configuration if you don't have something is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

CodeCaster is right it is the duplication. one more way to see your instance name is go to "Service" and look for "SQL Server" it will have SQL Server instance name .. if it is MSSQLServer then you can tye "." only else you should type ".\Instancename".