# What server name should i give while creating the new SQL Server database?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

I want to do database connection using SQL Server database. I am doing this connectivity in Visual Basic ASP.NET 2010, after right click on the database connection CREATE NEW SQL SERVER DATABASE window is open, here I want to give server name.

I tried using the server name `.\SQLEXPRESS` and my database name as `minedb`. But it won't accept those entries.

So what is the SQL Server name? please help me

Comment: That depends on whats the name of your server normally its your comp name

Comment: from where should i get this... on my pc sql-server 5.0 are installed

Comment: do you mean sql server 2005? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144487/how-to-find-server-name-for-sql-server-2005

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: User right click on "Start (list)"

Step 2: User left click on "System (menu item)"

Step 3: User left click on "Change settings (link)" in "System"

Step 4: User left click on "Change... (button)" in "System Properties"

Step 5: User right click on "Computer name: (edit)" in "Computer Name/Domain Changes"

Step 6: User left click on "Copy (menu item)"

Step 7: User left click on "Start Page - Microsoft Visual Studio (list item)"

Step 8: User right click on "Server name: (edit)" in "Create New SQL Server Database"

Step 9: User left click on "Paste (menu item)"

Step 10: User left click on "New database name: (edit)" in "Create New SQL Server Database"

Step 11: User keyboard input on "New database name: (edit)" in "Create New SQL Server Database"

Step 12: User left click on "OK (button)" in "Create New SQL Server Database"

Step 13: User left click in "Start Page - Microsoft Visual Studio"

Step 14: User left click in "Start Page - Microsoft Visual Studio"

Answer (score 0):

If you can get to a query window on Management Studio, you could do this:

```
SELECT @@SERVERNAME AS 'Server Name'
```

reference here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187944.aspx