# connect to sql server 2005

Tags: sql-server, database

I've been trying to connect to SQL Server 2005 on my `localhost` and I can not connect...
the server name textbox is empty and i tried to type different names but it doesn't work
and i choose authentication =sql server authentication

i receive the following message:

TITLE: Connect to Server

```
Cannot connect to LOCALHOST\SQLEXPRESS.
```

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:

Property Login was not set. (`Microsoft.SqlServer.Express.ConnectionInfo`)
 what should i type in `server name` textbox???
help please
thanks alot..

Comment: Try to connection with localhost, or IP address or your computer's. Name

Answer (score 0):

If the server name (textbox) is empty, most probably, you may have installed your SQL Server incorrectly....

i think you have the same problem with this guy, check this thread:

[How to find server name for SQL Server 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18144487/how-to-find-server-name-for-sql-server-2005)