# Determine installed sql server instances?

Tags: sql, sql-server

How can I determine which versions of SQL Server are installed on a machine? I know for sure on my own machine that I have SQL Server 2000 and SQL Server 2008 R2 but aside from just knowing this as I installed them how else can I find out? I've been tasked with finding out all the installed SQL Server instances on different servers so any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: you can use `SQL Server Configuration Manager`

Comment: Can you expand a little more?

Comment: @Downvoter please explain what was wrong so I dont make same mistakes in the future

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Connect to your Sql server DB server using SSMS and run the below command

```
Select @@version
```

Also, take a look at this Support/KB document for detailed way of getting the version/edition of SQL Server installed on your machine.

https://support.microsoft.com/kb/321185

To find the installed instances run `SQL server Configuration Manager` like

Start -> Microsoft SQL Server  -> Configuration Tools -> SQL Server Configuration Manager

Once config manager opened -> click/select the label named `Sql Server instances`

Other ways to find out the same; look at this posts

[How can I determine installed SQL Server instances and their versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions)

http://blogs.msdn.com/b/askjay/archive/2011/10/11/how-can-i-get-a-list-of-installed-sql-server-instances.aspx

To identify and enable disabled SQL Server instances in SQL Server 2000, see the below MS KB article.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953740

Comment: This only tells me the server instance im connected to, the machines I am checking have multiple instances installed and I am unsure how to see all installed instances?

Comment: in that case use `SQl Server Configuration Manager`.

Comment: Can you expand a little more please?

Comment: Cannot see sql server instances, see my comment in the answer by @NagarajS

Comment: See my edited answer again. This KB article explains how can you list out all SS2000 instance as well enable/disable them. Take help of `Google`; you will get most of your answer.

Comment: Perfect was just what I was looking for! Thank you

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT @@VERSION
```

from command line

```
SQLCMD -L
```

or use

SQl Server Configuration Manager

use the SQL Server Configuration Manager tool that installs with both `SQL Server 2005` and 2008. On the start menu, expand the `Microsoft SQL Server [YOURVERSION]` menu, and then expand the `Configuration Tools` submenu. Launch the `SQL Server Configuration Manager tool`

[image]

[Find your Installed SQL Server Versions and Instances](http://learningsqlserver.wordpress.com/2011/01/21/what-version-of-sql-server-do-i-have/)

[Identify a SQL Server Express Instance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165662%28v=sql.90%29.aspx)

[How to Find Your SQL Server Instances (Server Name)](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DLrxFXXeLFk)

[How to identify and enable disabled SQL Server instances in SQL Server 2000](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/953740)

[How can I determine installed SQL Server instances and their versions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions)

Comment: This is helpful thank you for image was very useful but when i tried this on a machine With sql 2005 and 2000 and this only showed sql 2005?