# Cannot open database "DatabaseName" requested by the login. The Login failed. Login failed for user

Tags: sql-server, vb.net, sql-server-2008-r2

Here is the scenario.I'm creating a desktop application with VB.NET (Windows Forms), and using SQL Server 2008 R2 for its database.

I have two computers (PC1 and PC2) and I want to connect PC2 to PC1.

PC 1 has the SQL Server database. What I do is I just copied .exe application in
the debug folder of my vb project and create a notepad for its connection and put them into one folder and transferred it to PC2.

When I run my application to other PC, I get an error

> Unhandled exception has occurred in your application. If you click
>   Continue, the application will ignore this error and attempt to
>   continue, If you click quit, The application will close immediately.
>
> Cannot open database "DatabaseName" requested by the login. The Login
>   failed. Login failed for user

My code inside the notepad

```
Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=DBSAS;Integrated Security=True
```

What I have done so far is to enable remote connection of SQL Server 2008 R2.

Can someone please give me an advice about this? I am really confused. Thanks

Comment: DataSource=. declares that SQL Server is on the same machine. Try with SQL Server Instance name instead of .

Comment: Are you able to connect to PC1 from PC2 using SSMS or some other tool to verify it's actually accessible?

Answer (score 1):

Specify `Data Source=PC1` in the connection string.  The `.` indicates a local SQL Server instance running on the same machine as the application.  The error suggests SQL Server is installed on PC2 but doesn't contain the desired database.

**EDIT:**

The error

> Cannot open database "DatabaseName" requested by the login

indicates authentication was successful to the SQL Server but the database context could not be set.  If `DatabaseName` in the error message is the same one as the `Initial Catalog` in the connection string, then either the database does not exist or the user does not have permissions to use it.  However, if the `DatabaseName` in the error message differs from the connection string, the connection string you changed is not the same one that is actually being used by the application.

Comment: i got the same error when changing to `Data Source=PC1` I just put that connection in a notepad. Is that right?

Comment: @DietherSilverious, yes, you can edit the connection string using the text editor of your choice.  Verify the application is actually using that connection string (i.e. it is not hard-coded).

Answer (score 1):

Hi please find sql server instance name at PC 1 using  below command

**OSQL -L**

replace . to the instance name  at you connection string.
Specify Data Source= "**sql server instance name** " in the connection string.

more detail are posted on below link.

[How can I determine installed SQL Server instances and their versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions).

Comment: Hi i got the same error. `Data Source=PC1;Initial Catalog=DBSAS;Integrated Security=True`. i have question.  I just put the connection in a notepad together with my .exe apps. Am i correct?

Comment: Are both server in same domain. and check under which user app is executing and then verify that user credential at db sever.

Comment: what about the user  are the same ?

Comment: Yes they are also the same

Comment: Can you try pinging sql server machine from app machine .

Comment: Yes they are pinging. It has a ping reply for both PC's

Answer (score 1):

On the second pc create a txt file on desktop. Something like `test.txt`. Then rename it to `test.udl` Universal Data Link. Double click the `test.udl`. From there you can produce a valid connection string to the SQL Server. After you are done open the udl file with notepad to get the connection string. Hope this helps.

Comment: I have followed your instructions but i have error `Login failed for user 'PC1/Guest` Can you help me on how to solve this. Thanks for your advice.

Comment: I would first try to connect as `sa` (system administrator). Not with integrated security.