# Retrieve all instances in sql server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, powershell, sqlcmd

I would like to retrieve all the sql server istances on my sql server. 
I found [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms165662(v=sql.90).aspx). With this sqlcmd utility I can retrieve the **currently-running** instance

```
select @@servername
go
```

but how can I have a list of all the instances in my sql server?

edit
the solution proposed in this post[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions) doesn't work.

I however found a solution using powershell using SQL Server Management Object [SMO](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms162169.aspx).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I determine installed SQL Server instances and their versions?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions)

Comment: The answer given in the duplicate you postes is not working. Maybe it was useful for older versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you some idea -

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'tempdb.dbo.#SQLServiceNames', N'U') IS NOT NULL
BEGIN   DROP TABLE #SQLServiceNames END
CREATE TABLE #SQLServiceNames (SQL_ServiceName VARCHAR(100))

INSERT INTO #SQLServiceNames 
EXEC xp_cmdshell 'sc query type= service state= all |find "SQL" |find /V "DISPLAY_NAME" |find /V "AD" | find /V "Writer"
```

The refer below link:
https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2609/checking-sql-services-status--an-evolution-part-1/