# SQL Server connect to 2014 not 2008

Tags: sql-server

I've had SQL Server 2008 R2 Express on my Windows 10 development machine for a long time but have had problems connecting to it via Object Explorer. I gave up a while ago and started using another machine. I recently installed SQL Server 2014 Express on the original machine. Now, I am puzzled. When I first ran the installation of 2014 via SSMS it connected okay and there were no databases listed. At the top of Object Explorer it showed I was running SQL Server 12.0.4232. The next time I opened 2014 using SSMS it has connected to the 2008 R2 instance and all my old databases are there. It shows SQL Server 10.0.4000 as the version at the top of Object Explorer.

Now, I open SSMS 2014 and connect to my machine and, every time, it opens the 2008 R2 instance. How do I tell SSMS 2014 that I want to open the 2014 SQL Server Express edition I just installed, not the 2008 RD edition that has been on there for years?

Comment: Apparently you need to specify the [instance name](http://stackoverflow.com/q/141154/11683) you set for the new SQL Server.

Comment: You probably installed a new version and did not do a in place upgrade, now you have two copied running.