# Change server name to localhost SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, ssms-2014

I am using SQL Server 2014 and I am logging in using a server name of `(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB` using Windows authentication and user login. I want to change it to localhost for my development purpose.

When I use server name `localhost`, I get this error:

[image]

Comment: Looks like you already have an instance of some version of SQL Server at localhost. The default instance.

Comment: @MartinSmith how i change it to localhost instead of  (localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB  ???

Comment: You can't change it to `localhost` since you're using the **SQL Server Express LocalDB** instance - which has a fixed instance name that must be supplied. If you use just "localhost", you're trying to connect to the **default** (unnamed) instance of SQL Server on your machine (if that exists)

Comment: First work out if you already have a server running at localhost https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions. If you already have one running on localhost (looks like you do) then you need to take ownership, i.e. become admin, and restore your database on to it. Then you can connect to it.