# Upgrading SQL Management from Express 2012 to Enterprise 2016

Tags: sql-server, database-connection, connection-string, iis-10

I am migrating my Webappserver from SQL2012Express to SQL2016Enterprise. 
for this  I have installed a Windows server 2016 with IIS10 my current IIS db connection String is

> "data source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=|DataDirectory|aspnetdb.mdf;User Instance=true"

this is on Windows 2008 and IIS 7 with SQL 2012 Express.

Now on the new webappserver my source is no longer SQLexpress since the SQL is enterprise not express.  my instance name was SQL2012 I changed it to Sql2016 in my Software's web.config and IIS as well I am not able to connect my software to the Database.

Here is what my current Db String is on the current webappserver.[image]

My SQL management Studio is 
[image]

On the New Server My ISS db connection string is the same which is express? [image]

and my SQL Studio properties are [image]

My connection string in my MVC app web.config file is

> 

I hope I am giving you enough information to help me on this challenge I am facing.

This is my first time migrating SQL server and I am sure  I have create the instance correctly. 
my connection String to the site on IIS is

> data source=.\SQL2016;Integrated Security=True;App=Worldwide;Initial Catalog=Worldwide

Any Help is very, very appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: are you asking how to migrate from sql server 2012 express version to sql server enterprise 2016..I am not sure what is the ask here

Comment: No, I have done all of the migration. my software loads, but when I try to log in I am getting Error 500 (Internal server Error) and I know this happening because my software cannot open the database.and the only error I can see in my migration is the ISS Connection String is showing SQLEXPRESS,  which I have highlighted in the image above. I have SQL Enterprise? where do I get this SQLExpress Instance in the String  I don't know. I have looked everywhere I cannot find where the do I need to correct this/

Comment: you need to add a new connection string,express wont work..check out this link to know more on how to find instance names(https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions),then add that instance,but prior to that,try checking if you are able to connect from local machine and report machine(check out for links on how to enable sql server remote connections ),finally add this in connection string along with port number

Comment: @TheGameiswar Thank you for your replies. I know my SQL Instance I have created the instance myself. which is Sql2016. Yes I am able to connect locally and remotely, I can see all my tables, I can select into any Table. I am able to run  sqlcmd -S AppServer\Sql2016 using power shell and I am able to access my Database. My issue is on the IIS side under  "Server Name" > Connection Strings. There is SQLEpxress as my data source, so what does it have to be instead SQLxpress if your software is Enterprise not Express ?

Comment: AppServer\Sql2016  plus port number