# How to find a list of local MS SQL Servers?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, cmd

I looked at [How can I determine installed SQL Server instances and their versions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/141154/how-can-i-determine-installed-sql-server-instances-and-their-versions) already but CMD returns nothing:

```
C:\Windows\system32>sqlcmd -L

C:\Windows\system32>
```

But when using Visual Studio (v2019), I go to `View > SQL Server Object Explorer`, I see two SQL Server instances with system databases inside. One is called `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB` and the other `(LocalDB)\ProjectsV13`.

Both are using SQL Server 2016 (v13.0.4001). Using that I was able to connect through SSMS 2018 as well.

My question is: why aren't these instances showing up in the command line? And can I delete one of the server instance? Why are there two?

Comment: Is the SQL Server Browser service running?

Comment: @AndrewMorton I checked my services and I there is only SQL Server VSS write. everything else is irrelevant to SQL. I looked up in SQL Server configuration manager but SQL Server services is empty there as well. I checked in C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\90\Shared and sqlbrowser.exe was not there also.

Comment: Have you seen [Why does sqlcmd -Lc not show the local instance?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/18499/143697)

Comment: @AndrewMorton thank you for the link. I had a look but unfortunately the solution takes me to SQL Server Configuration Manager and I still have no SQL Server  Service instances to work with there. Also, since I'm accessing a local server instance, I doubt there would be problems with UDP packet loss.

Comment: If the UDP packets are not allowed through the firewall then there will be 100% packet loss, so that is something to check.

Comment: I just tried setting up inbound and outbound rules on TCP 1433 and UDP 1434 to allow connections. Failed again with nothing returned from cmd. Is there a way to check error logs?

Comment: [How do I access a firewall log (Windows 10 w. Windows Defender)](https://security.stackexchange.com/q/166875/114527).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/212442/discussion-between-shervin-rad-and-andrew-morton).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using SSMS, in the connection manager typing the following in the server name box does it:

1. `.`
2. open cmd and type `hostname`, and use that
3. `(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB`
4. `(LocalDB)\ProjectsV13` I think this depends on the installation

Comment: 3. (LocalDB)/MSSQLLocalDB should be (LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB