# enum all values from a subkey

Tags: winapi, api, registry

I have a subkey in my registry with an unknown numbers of values.

I want to get all the data from those values in th specified subkey.

how can I do that ? I don't know the names of the values and the number of values.

I'm programming in C.

thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a code for geting all string values a from given regkey (you must open this key before and close after using this function.

```
vector<pair<wstring, wstring>> CRegistryManager::getKeyValues(HKEY regKey)
{
    vector<pair<wstring, wstring>> retValues;

    DWORD numOfValues;
    DWORD maxValueNameLen;
    DWORD maxValueDataLen;
    LONG retCode;

    retCode = RegQueryInfoKey(regKey, NULL, NULL,NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, &numOfValues, &maxValueNameLen, &maxValueDataLen, NULL, NULL);
    if( (retCode == ERROR_SUCCESS) && (numOfValues != 0) )
    {
        TCHAR* valueName = new TCHAR[maxValueNameLen+1];

        TCHAR* valueData = new TCHAR[maxValueDataLen+1];

        for(int i = 0; i < numOfValues; i++)
        {
            DWORD valueNameBuferSize = maxValueNameLen+1;
            DWORD valueDataBufferSize = maxValueDataLen+1;

            retCode = RegEnumValue(regKey, i, valueName, &valueNameBuferSize, NULL,NULL, (LPBYTE)valueData, &valueDataBufferSize);
            if(retCode == ERROR_SUCCESS)
            {
                auto pair = make_pair(wstring(valueName), wstring(valueData));
                retValues.push_back(pair);
            }
        }
        delete[] valueName;
        delete[] valueData;
    }
    return retValues;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to use the Win32 API [RegEnumValue](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724865(VS.85).aspx) to enumerate the registry values of a subkey.  There is an [example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms724256(VS.85).aspx) on MSDN which is similar to this but for enumerating registry subkeys.

You can also find some helper functions from one of my previous answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065/how-to-read-a-value-from-the-windows-registry/35717#35717).