# Read all data in a registry key

Tags: winapi

How do you read all the data in a registry key

```cpp
    void get_reg_value(HKEY handle ,  std::string value_to_read)
    {
        
        char value[2048];
        DWORD BufferSize = 8192;
        
        LONG errorcode = RegGetValueA(handle, NULL, value_to_read.c_str(), RRF_RT_REG_MULTI_SZ, NULL, (PVOID)&value, &BufferSize);
        wprintf(L"Value data: %s\n", (PWSTR)value);


    }
```

The key to read is `HARDWARE\\DESCRIPTION\\System` and the subkey is `SystemBiosVersion` which has the value

```
ALASKA - 1072009
F6
American Megatrends - 5000C
```

but I only get

```
Value data: ALASKA - 1072009
```

Comment: MULTI_SZ is a NULL-terminated list of NULL-terminated strings. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6685134/179634).

Comment: From [registry value types](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/sysinfo/registry-value-types): *"`REG_MULTI_SZ`: A sequence of null-terminated strings, terminated by an empty string (\0)."* The documentation for [`RegGetValue`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winreg/nf-winreg-reggetvaluew) has more information on how this data type is returned.

Answer (score 0):

First off, you are passing in the wrong `BufferSize` value to `RegGetValueA()`.  You are claiming that you have allocated 8KB of memory, but you have actually allocated only 2KB.  If the Registry data exceeds 2KB, you will overflow your buffer and corrupt memory.  NEVER lie about your buffer sizes.

Also, you are trying to print out a *narrow* ANSI string as-if it were a *wide* Unicode string, which it is not, so that is also wrong.

That being said, a `REG_MULTI_SZ` value is a null-terminated list of **multiple** null-terminated strings.  You are printing out only the 1st string in the list.  You need to loop through the whole list until you encounter the final null terminator, eg:

```cpp
void get_reg_value(HKEY handle, std::string value_to_read)
{
    char Buffer[2048];
    DWORD BufferSize = sizeof(Buffer);
        
    LONG errorcode = RegGetValueA(handle, NULL, value_to_read.c_str(), RRF_RT_REG_MULTI_SZ, NULL, Buffer, &BufferSize);
    if (errorcode == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        char *value = Buffer;
        while (*value != '\0') {
            printf("Value data: %s\n", value);
            value += (strlen(value) + 1);
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Error: %ld\n", errorcode);
    }
}
```

Alternatively, if needed, consider using a dynamically allocated buffer, so can handle data values greater than 2KB:

```cpp
void get_reg_value(HKEY handle, std::string value_to_read)
{
    std::vector<char> Buffer(2048);
    DWORD BufferSize = Buffer.size();
        
    LONG errorcode;
    do {
        errorcode = RegGetValueA(handle, NULL, value_to_read.c_str(), RRF_RT_REG_MULTI_SZ, NULL, Buffer, &BufferSize);
        if (errorcode != ERROR_MORE_DATA) break;
        Buffer.resize(BufferSize);
    }
    while (true);

    if (errorcode == ERROR_SUCCESS) {
        char *value = Buffer.data();
        while (*value != '\0') {
            printf("Value data: %s\n", value);
            value += (strlen(value) + 1);
        }
    }
    else {
        printf("Error: %ld\n", errorcode);
    }
}
```