# Reading Registry in Windows 7 behaving strangely

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-7

I am trying to read registry's "(Default)" values in Windows 7 in c++, and following is the code I am using:

```
string GetSZValueUnique( HKEY openKey, const char* regkey, const char* keyName )
{
   HKEY hKey = 0;
   BYTE data[512] ;
   DWORD szsize = 512 ;
   string value ;

   LONG retValue = RegOpenKeyEx( openKey, regkey, 0, KEY_READ, &hKey ) ;

   if ( retValue == ERROR_SUCCESS )
   {
        LONG retV = RegQueryValueEx( hKey, keyName, 0, 0, data, &szsize ) ;
        if ( retV == ERROR_SUCCESS )
        {
           char* _value = reinterpret_cast<char*>(data) ;
           value = _value ;

           RegCloseKey (hKey) ;
           return value ;
        }
        else
        {
            char msg[512] ;
            FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,0,(DWORD)retV,0,&msg[0],512,0) ;
            error_string = &msg[0];
            MessageBox( 0, error_string.c_str(), "Query : GetSZValueUnique", 0 );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        char msg[512] ;
        FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM,0,(DWORD)retV,0,&msg[0],512,0) ;
        error_string = &msg[0];
        MessageBox( 0, error_string.c_str(), "Open : GetSZValueUnique", 0 );
    }

    RegCloseKey (hKey) ;
    return "" ;
}
```

**And this is how I am calling the above function :**

```
string ts3 = GetSZValueUnique( HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, "SOFTWARE\\TeamSpeak 3 Client\\", "" );
if ( !ts3.empty() )
    MessageBox( 0, ts3.c_str(), "GetSZValueUnique", 0 );
```

For some Keys it works for some it doesn't : For example, it works for "Adobe", "TrendMicro", "CheckPoint", "RegisteredApplications" but not for "7-Zip", "RTLSetup", "Sonic", "TeamSpeak 3 Client"

I am out of ideas now, can somebody point out what's wrong ?

**EDIT:** I have checked the code with "(Default)" values and other values as well, for keys its not working it never goes past the *"if ( retValue == ERROR_SUCCESS )"* check and I always get "*Specified file not found*" error. For keys its working, it gets past the "*if ( retValue == ERROR_SUCCESS )*" check and returns the value if its present, if its not present it simply displays the error message "*Specified file not found*".

**EDIT 2:** I Checked again : and it seems the keys it works for have their corresponding clone in "Wow6432Node" subkey under SOFTWARE... hmmm... so how do I get it working ?

Comment: What behavior are you experiencing? Have you manually checked if there is any data for the latter entries?

Comment: First, is your app 64bit or 32bit, second, have you noticed a difference in your algorithm "working" when your 32bit app looks up 32bit associated apps, or your 64bit app looks up 64bit associated apps, but when you mix the two things don't seem to work? If so, google [Wow6432Node](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: @bash.d Updated the original question.

Comment: @WhozCraig my app is 32 bit which works under Administrator Previlages, all the keys I tested were of 64bit apps. I Checked again , and it seems the keys it works for have their corresponding clone in "Wow6432Node" subkey under SOFTWARE... hmmm... so how do I get it working

Comment: @StudentX click on the [link provided](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724072(v=vs.85).aspx) in my comment and start reading, specifically read up on using the [KEY_WOW64_64KEY and KEY_WOW64_32KEY](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384129(v=vs.85).aspx) flags for accessing the "other" side.

Comment: @WhozCraig is quite right. You need to read about the registry redirector and understand it. Don't skip that step. It is crucial that you understand the redirector.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can specify the flag::

1. "**KEY_WOW64_32KEY**" in "**samDesired**" parameter of the **RegOpenKeyEx** if you want to access Wow6432Node Keys i.e., **32-bit keys** from your app.
2. "**KEY_WOW64_64KEY**" in "**samDesired**" parameter of the **RegOpenKeyEx** if you want to access normal Keys i.e., **64-bit keys** from your app.

Note:: Your doubt has already been cleared by @WhozCraig in comments with the suitable links. If he answers, do accept his answer over mine.