# Is there any way to get MachineGuid using win32 API call (not reading it maually from registry)?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

Is there any way to get MachineGuid using win32 API  call (not reading it maually from registry)?

Comment: There's a registry entry for this under HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Cryptography\MachineGuid you can read the registry using the Windows API. Look at this other post about [Reading from Registry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065/how-to-read-a-value-from-the-windows-registry)

Comment: The question was if there is an API call to get its value directly (because you cant be sure if that Registry Key existed on Windows XP SP1 and still exists on current Windows 8.1 and future ms products, can you?)

Comment: It's stored in the registry, so any other API would need to get it from there as well (stored during Windows setup). What do you need it for? Maybe there is something else you could use such as the MAC Address for uniquely identifying your user.

Comment: You are asking for teleportation.  Reading from the registry requires winapi calls, they are not fundamentally different from some other winapi call you hope is available.  WMI is another way to get it, unlikely you'll enjoy that much in C++.  Getting an id that globally unique to identify a machine is never difficult, just make your own.  Save it in a file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to get the [GUID](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc739558%28v=ws.10%29.aspx) using the WMI [Win32_ComputerSystemProduct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) class.

Comment: Looks grate, could you provide minimalistic example of how to use this in C++ programm?

Comment: [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa390418(v=vs.85).aspx)  provides plenty of examples.