# how to get BIOS information in c++

Tags: c++, c, bios

we are working on something in that requires BIOS information, i know that these information is available in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/HARDWARE/DESCRIPTION/System registry setting. But i need to do this in C++. 
is there any API available for this?? i dont want to read from the system registry due to some limitation on client system.
Is there any other way to do this??

Comment: [How to read a value from the Windows registry](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34065/how-to-read-a-value-from-the-windows-registry)

Answer (score 1):

If you already know that the values are stored in a registry hive, then you could use [CRegKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xka57xy4.aspx) to read the values. This is just an ATL wrapper around Windows registry manipulation APIs.

If you want to use a Windows API instead, there's [RegQueryValueEx](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724911(v=vs.85).aspx).

Keine has also given you an excellent link in a comment, which discusses several things and also has a link that's detailing the 32/64 bit registry gotchas.

Comment: thanks for your response. but i don't want to use system registry is there any other way available to get this info. thanks in advance..

Comment: Have you had a look at the Win32_BIOS class? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394077(v=vs.85).aspx